# R - Using ungroup() on my dataframe is breaking my functions?

Tags: r

I have the following example dataframe:

```
countries = c("Australia", "Australia", "Chile", "Chile", "Brazil", "Brazil", "Brazil")
techs = c("AI", "AI", "AI", "Bio", "AI", "Bio", "computers")
value = c(404, 402, 2313, 424, 1424, 2141, 214)
year = c(2018, 2019,2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018)

df = data.frame(countries, techs, value, year)
```

I have a function which calculates the total value for each country per tech (essentially summing the years for each tech and country):

```
country_tech = function(data, tech, country){
  result =  data %>% 
    select(countries, techs, value) %>% 
    filter(countries == country) %>% 
    filter(techs == tech) %>% 
    summarise(Total = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))
  
}
```

I create a new dataframe which groups the countries/tech and drops the years so I can append new data to it:

```
df2 = select(df, countries, techs) %>%  group_by(countries, techs) %>% distinct()
```

I then create a new column in my new dataframe using the function which sums up the tech value for each country:

```
df2 = df2 %>% mutate(value = country_tech(df, techs, countries ))
```

This all works fine. But as I did not ungroup when making `df2`, I am having issues spreading the data.

If I add an `ungroup()` e.g.:

```
df2 = select(df, countries, techs) %>%  group_by(countries, techs) %>% distinct() %>% ungroup()
```

Then my function no longer works and I get the following errors:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `value`.
x Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 4 or 1, not size 6.
i Input `..1` is `techs == tech`.
i Input `value` is `country_tech(df, techs, countries)`.
```

Does anyone have an idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Further update** you have named the mutated column twice that's why the problem.

use it like this and it'll work (don't give the name of column further as you have already given it in custom function)

```
df2 %>% group_by(techs, countries) %>% mutate(country_tech(df, techs, countries)) %>% ungroup() %>%
  spread(techs, value)
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  countries    AI   Bio computers
  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 Australia   806    NA        NA
2 Brazil     1424  2141       214
3 Chile      2313   424        NA
```

**Update**

Actually your column names generated through function method are the problem area.  See if you proceed like this, it'll work.

```
#ungrouping as you desire
df2 = select(df, countries, techs) %>%  group_by(countries, techs) %>% distinct() %>% ungroup()

#mutating with custom function
df2 %>% group_by(techs, countries) %>% mutate(value = country_tech(df, techs, countries)) %>% ungroup()
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  countries techs     value$Total
  <chr>     <chr>           <dbl>
1 Australia AI                806
2 Chile     AI               2313
3 Chile     Bio               424
4 Brazil    AI               1424
5 Brazil    Bio              2141
6 Brazil    computers         214
```

Notice the column names in above result

```
# using pivot_wider instead of spread
df2 %>% group_by(techs, countries) %>% mutate(value = country_tech(df, techs, countries)) %>% ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = techs, values_from = value)

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  countries AI$Total Bio$Total computers$Total
  <chr>        <dbl>     <dbl>           <dbl>
1 Australia      806        NA              NA
2 Chile         2313       424              NA
3 Brazil        1424      2141             214
```

**Old answer** I wonder why aren't you using this to get your final output

```
df %>% group_by(countries, techs) %>% summarise(value_total = sum(value)) %>% ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  countries techs     value_total
  <chr>     <chr>           <dbl>
1 Australia AI                806
2 Brazil    AI               1424
3 Brazil    Bio              2141
4 Brazil    computers         214
5 Chile     AI               2313
6 Chile     Bio               424
```

ungroup() is redundant in this one too.

**Edit** Still if you want to use custom function, try this

```
df2 = select(df, countries, techs) %>%  group_by(countries, techs) %>% slice_head()
```

Comment: I have quite a few functions that do multiple things such as total values per country, per tech. For the purpose of providing a working example, I stuck to one function.

Comment: Sorry, popped out for lunch. Looking now, thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately its the same issue before. If you add "%>% spread(techs, value)" to the end of "df2 = df2 %>% mutate(value = country_tech(df, techs, countries ))" it errors out with "undefined columns selected". Ho hum

Comment: Hmm. Still doesnt work. I will figure it out, I am too late for my work submission so will play around over the weekend :).... thank you again for your help! (Oh, tried pivot_wider, doesnt work.. as essentially each value in the cell is a vector of all the numbers)

Comment: YES, THANK YOU! ... working perfectly, thank you so much for your perserverance with this! I am really thankful as this will be so helpful for future work!

Comment: Glad to have been of help.  Meanwhile see further edit.

Answer (score 1):

Having a function that takes the original dataset and filters some values in each call is inefficient. You should rather split the dataset by the terms you want and then apply some function to the dataset. If you wnat to do "multiple things" I assume you want your function to return a data frame that with more than one value (add them to the `summarise` function). You could do it on `nest`ed data.

```
country_tech = function(data_subset){
  data_subset %>% 
    summarise(Total = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))
}

df %>% 
  group_by(countries, techs) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, country_tech)) %>% 
  unnest(data)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   countries, techs [9]
  countries techs     Total
  <fct>     <fct>     <dbl>
1 Australia AI          806
2 Chile     AI         2313
3 Chile     Bio         424
4 Brazil    AI         1424
5 Brazil    Bio        2141
6 Brazil    computers   214
```